# Stuck on "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, kernel, dpkg

I have a problem with uninstalling packages on my server(20.04 LTS).

When I run `apt remove metricbeat` receive this message:

```
root@elk:/home/elk# apt remove metricbeat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  metricbeat
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 182 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 151385 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing metricbeat (7.16.2) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic (5.4.0-92.103) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic (5.4.0-92.103) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic

Progress: [ 80%] [############################################.......]
```

It freezes on this step, ctrl+c ctrl+z didn't work.
I open another ssh connection and run again `apt remove metricbeat` and receive this message:

```
^Citing for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 1890890 (apt)... 1s
```

I found apt PID with `ps -aux | grep apt`  and kill it.
Then run again remove command now:

```
root@elk:/home/elk# apt remove metricbeat
^Citing for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock. It is held by process 1891272 (dpkg)... 1s
```

dpkg running processes:

```
root     1891272  0.0  0.0  11136  5328 ?        Ss   14:47   0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 42 --configure --pending
root     1891282  0.0  0.0   2608   608 ?        S    14:47   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic.postinst triggered linux-update-5.4.0-92-generic
```

after killing those process run again package remove command and get:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

so I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it stuck on this step:

```
root@elk:/home/elk# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic (5.4.0-92.103) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic (5.4.0-92.103) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic
```

By ctrl+c :

```
error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic
```

I checked the /boot :

```
root@elk:/boot# ls -lh
total 218M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233K Apr 20  2020 config-5.4.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233K Nov  5 16:02 config-5.4.0-91-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233K Nov 26 14:42 config-5.4.0-92-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Apr  9 08:14 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Apr  9 08:14 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78M Feb 15  2021 initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81M Dec  9 06:37 initrd.img-5.4.0-91-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr  9 14:58 initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic.new
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jan  5 06:48 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-91-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4.6M Apr 20  2020 System.map-5.4.0-26-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4.6M Nov  5 16:02 System.map-5.4.0-91-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4.6M Nov 26 14:42 System.map-5.4.0-92-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jan  5 06:48 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-92-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  12M Apr 20  2020 vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  12M Nov  5 16:04 vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  14M Nov 26 14:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-92-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jan  5 06:48 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic
root@elk:/boot#
```

I think it has some problems with `initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic` and I don't know how can I solve it.
this cycle happened again and again.

Comment: Just to be clear: the problem is not about installing or uninstalling (that's a consequence). The problem is about a package not completing its installation: `1 not fully installed or removed.` for `linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic` so you can focus the topic.

Answer (score 1):

How long are you waiting? I know that I have had to wait for several minutes while it is doing `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img`. Try grabbing a coffee and watching some TV when it gets there.

Comment: Answer unrelated

Answer (score 1):

Try running `update-initramfs` in verbose mode, to see on which module it gets stuck:

```
update-initramfs -v -u
```

Or `ps` might show you which hook is currently running:

```
ps f | grep initram
  24830 pts/1    S+     0:00          \_ /bin/sh -e /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.19.0-21-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64
  24832 pts/1    S+     0:00              \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -c -k 4.19.0-21-amd64 -b /boot
  24834 pts/1    S+     0:00                  \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-21-amd64.new 4.19.0-21-amd64
  28372 pts/1    S+     0:00                      \_ /bin/sh /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mdadm
```